# Algumas opções de fechamento estão em inglês

Tags: bug

Ao tentar sinalizar uma pergunta em `sinalizar/deveria ser fechada...` as opções para `não está clara o suficiente` e `principalmente baseada em opiniões` estão com suas descrições no idioma inglês:

> [image: screenshot da tela de fechamento]

Comment: Isso geralmente acontece quando eles fazem algum *merge* com as traduções e mudam o texto e/ou o texto em inglês sobrescreve o em português. No [traducir.win](https://pt.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Please%20clarify) há uma dessas mensagens não traduzida, talvez seja justamente essa que foi exibida.

Comment: Entendi, também imaginei que pudesse ser isso mas não sabia de fato o que pudesse ser! Grato @AndersonCarlosWoss!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acrescentei as traduções, imagino que estarão no ar até amanhã.